# Why does my UIBezierPath mask still allow content to be drawn inside, despite it being "donut" shaped?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect, uibezierpath

I have a UIBezierPath in a circular donut shape:

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 32.0, height: 32.0))
ovalPath.lineWidth = 5
ovalPath.stroke()
```

And when I draw it:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let testShape = UIImage(named: "test-shape")!
CGContextSaveGState(context)
ovalPath.addClip()
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, rect, testShape.CGImage)
CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

Despite the mask being a donut, content still draws "inside", making the mask basically just a circle instead of being a hollow circle. How do I make it respect the fact that there's no inside?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a donut-shaped path, you still have an oval. An stroked oval path.
What you want is a path composed of two ovals. 
Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106).

And this is how you do it:

remove:

```
ovalPath.lineWidth = 5
ovalPath.stroke()
```

create donut-shape with a 5px wide border:

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 32.0, height: 32.0))
ovalPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true;
path.appendPath(UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 27.0, height: 27.0)))
```

Comment: With that I'm not able to use line caps though, am I?